# after upgrading asp.net core mvc 2.2 to 3.0 application deployed into IIS 7.5, 8.5 is not working

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

***After upgrading asp.net core 2.2 to 3.0. It is perfectly working in my local machine but after deploying into IIS 7.5, 8.5 it is not working showing the following error message:***

**500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.**

Steps that i did:

1. after upgrading to asp.net core 3.0 it was successfully working
   in my local machine.
2. installed ASP.NET Core Runtime 3.0.1  hosting bundle in server
   machine
3. ran the application  but it has not worked getting 500 Internal
   server error.
4. uninstalled the ASP.NET Core Runtime previous versions like 2.2
   hosting bundle in server machine
5. again tried still getting the same 500 Internal server error
6. went to iis log files and got the following info but i did not
   understand that

`#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 8.5

## Version: 1.0

## Date: 2019-12-09 08:53:29

## Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken

2019-12-09 08:53:29 ServerIP GET / - 99 - clientIP Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/78.0.3904.108+Safari/537.36 - 500 21 13 171
2019-12-09 08:53:29 ServerIP  GET /favicon.ico - 99 - clientIP Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/78.0.3904.108+Safari/537.36 https://ServerIP:99/ 500 21 13 46`

Comment: Hi. You should try to get some more detailed logs. What you have shared doesn't really tell anything about what is going wrong.

Comment: Hi Dear, Thanks for your response i got  following windows log message:  A fatal alert was received from the remote endpoint. The TLS protocol defined fatal alert code is 46.

Comment: In web.config file enable the stdoutLogEnabled and post the error logs here.

Comment: i did the same stdoutLogEnabled = true in my web config file and i posted that log file whatever i got..  please see at 6th point. and  Windows system log message is  A fatal alert was received from the remote endpoint. The TLS protocol defined fatal alert code is 46

Comment: As far as I know, the 500 error will contains the details error message. Could you please post the details error message? Besides, I suggest you could check your IIS module to make sure you have the aspnetcorev2 module.

Comment: Hi Dear, I am not getting much info about that 500 Internal error whatever i got i posted above. Actually i got to know that It is my certificate issue. i created new Certificate then it is working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. It's a certificate issue i created new certificate then it is working fine now